# Will Kindle Direct Publishing maintain my formatting around images

Tags: kindle, formatting, kdp

I know KDP can upload Word documents. I have a large part of my book completed and I want to include images. I know they will be displayed in black and white on a Kindle, but what about formatting? I want to be able to wrap my text around an image like the sample I have provided below. Will KDP respect/handle this formatting?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Kindle help page info might provide options:
[Kindle Create page.](https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/G7R2L7V5X6SJH948)
That web link (in the "**Add or change images**" section) suggests to upload .doc into Kindle Create, save it, and THEN insert your images/charts into that open file and place each image where you need them (it allows formatting the images there).

I have attached an example where the top image was already on the .doc page when it was uploaded into Kindle Create, whereas the lower image was inserted inside of Kindle Create and formatted there. For unknown reason Kindle dumped the formatting on the top image (the image that was already in my Word document).

Inserting images into Kindle Create seems like a convoluted method (especially if the text document has a ton of charts and images that you prefer to refine into place before going into Kindle Create). Ideally building it all in your favorite software (whether Adobe / Corel / MS Word etc.) is the most preferred method by book/eBook designers.

Other web sources (including Kindle help page) indicate it is feasible to set the images/charts in your Word document (and formatting it all there) before uploading the document into Kindle Create.

Hopefully another person can comment here with a solution that'll work via MS Word (your preferred software), since I primarily use other software to reach final eBook stage.

Browse some of these eBook creation options at this link below. One of those eBook software tools should be quite viable for your needs (and a number of those are free, or low cost).
[eBook design software](https://technicalwall.com/software-reviews/ebook-creator/)

Examples are Designrr, Jasper AI, Kotobee, Canva, Visme, Bit.ai, VistaCreate, Flipsnack, Adobe, Marq, Ulysses, Blurb, Google Docs, Pages ibooks, Sigil, Pressbooks, Vellum, Beacon, Lulu.

Hopefully another commenter here can give more pointers on MS Word and image/text wrap solution for you (since the KDP specs imply it should work).

[image: example document with two images]

Comment: Hi granite, really appreciate the time you took to answer this and it definitely helps me. What software do you use to reach final ebook stage? Curious to know.

Comment: Depends on the project.
For 'fixed layout' ebook projects we use Adobe which makes the export to PDF quick and accurate with few unanticipated variances in KDP Previewer. 

For 'reflowable' ebooks, the base is usually started with Jutoh then progresses to direct coding refinement (to match KDP specs), though on the latest projects we've just gone direct coding all the way. 

By learning the direct internal code of Epub3.0 (such as the mimetype, container, .ncx, .opf, toc.xhtml etc ) it makes direct refinement much easier to process (by learning the key code structure).